# using data-action with cocoon:after-insert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem, cocoonjs, stimulusjs

I am converting some older JS into stimulus.

```
$(document).on('cocoon:after-insert', function(e, element) {
  $some_inputs.change(updateMethodName)
})
```

The cocoon add partial looks like

```
= link_to_add_association 'Add Something', f, :method, partial: 'path/some_fields', class: 'btn btn-primary', 'data-action': 'click->stimulus-controller.someMethod'
```

This is te HTML outout

```
<a class="btn btn-primary add_fields" data-action="click->stimulus-controller.someMethod" data-association="..." data-associations="..." data-association-insertion-template="..." href="#">Add Something</a>
```

Now someMethod us working as I am calling it on connect
but I am having problems calling it from the user interface.

Comment: Please clarify: if I understand correctly, you were using the callbacks before, and you now want to use stimulus? And that is not working I guess? Or what is happening and what are you expecting to be happening? My 2 cents: cocoon will attach js to the link_to_add_association and will probably block other js or vice versa. I think you should either use stimulus all the way or cocoon.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this is

```
<a class="btn btn-primary add_fields" data-action="click->stimulus-controller.someMethod" data-association="..." data-associations="..." data-association-insertion-template="..." href="#">Add Something</a>
```

should change to

```
<a class="btn btn-primary add_fields" data-action="click->stimulus-controller#someMethod" data-association="..." data-associations="..." data-association-insertion-template="..." href="#">Add Something</a>
```

the `.` needs to change to `#`